# Cannot install ia32-lib package

Tags: multiarch

I have several programs that reuquire 32 bit packages (pointing to the ia32-lib package). However, when I try to install it, this happens.

```
spirit@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

No big whoop, packages die all the time. I tried a month later however and I still got this error, trying to install the specific package produces this error.

```
spirit@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs-multiarch is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ia32-libs-multiarch' has no installation candidate
```

I am no Linux whizz-kid, but this seems to be that the package doesn't exist. I searched for Skype in the software centre (I was told this installs the 32-bit packages) and it does not appear in the software centre, and the downloadable from their website produces an error about - funnily enough - no 32-bit packages.

Anyone who helps me will get a medal from the gods with the weight of a thousand planets. Just don't wear it for god's sake.

Comment: Did you install a 64-bit (amd64) Ubuntu or a 32-bit (i386) version? You can also see from `uname -a` in a terminal.

Comment: I installed a 64 bit version of Ubuntu, as every time I install via Wubi it will always grab the amd64. I'm not sure if it is worth getting the 32-bit version instead since the 64 bit has a few compatibility problems especially like this.

Comment: Nevermind, clearly this is just one of those hard to fix problems that comes with every release (usually it is hardware related, software is new to me). I'll just install a 32-bit version instead. I hope a solution is found soon for all those with 64-bit, I believe in you folk!

Comment: Sounds very much like you don't have an i386 foreign architecture. What's the output of `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like installing through WUBI did not correctly detect the available foreign architectures. As tumbleweed suggested printing the foreign architectures probably returns nothing. Add i386 as a foreign architecture, update the apt cache, then install the 32 bit libs.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: This worked for me. So many other stupid people out there trying to answer this question - they all have it wrong. so many people keep talking about skype too. Some people just need ia32libs, not skype LOL.

Comment: Sadly this does not work on 13.10. Any workaround?

Comment: This worked for me on Crunchbang 3.2.0-4. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work with 16.04

Answer (score 2):

Scotty's answer works great for 12.10, but if you are on 12.04, then `dpkg` does not support `--add-architecture`. Just try:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then try installing ia32-libs as

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

But it is probably better to install the meta package ia32-libs-multiarch instead.

Comment: I am on 12.04, None of them helped me out. Doing "sudo apt-get update" and then "sudo apt-get install ia32-libs" gives me error - The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch, and doing "sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch" - gives me a few other unmet dependencies.

Comment: Paste the actual error so one will be able to help you out. Without seeing actual error, there is not much anyone can do.

Comment: But, I have mentioned the errors - the following packages have unmet dependencies. Check it again please.

Answer (score 1):

- Install Synaptic from terminal window

  ```
  sudo apt-get install synaptic
  ```
- Launch Synaptic and goto “settings > Repositories”
- Click “other software > add”
- Insert this line in the box `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse`
- Click ok and close Synaptic
- In terminal `sudo apt-get update`
- In terminal `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`
- Fresh Install

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install them from the **Ubuntu Software Center**? It should locate us directly the package we're looking for. Search for "ia32", locate `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386` and `ia32-libs` and install them.

[image: ia32-libs-multiarch:i386]

If that doesn't solve the problem, try changing the server from **Edit** > **Software Sources** and run update from **Update Manager** or `sudo apt-get-update` before trying to install again.

Answer (score 0):

Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package ! Installation Error

While installing kingsoft office I faced OS bit version problem ( a well known error but without proper answer) `The following packages have unmet dependencies:  ia32-libs: 
Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch but it is not installed` . I tried ~50 solutions but none of them worked. After that I followed ubuntu terminal instruction and omg it has solved my problem.

When I fired the command I got following message,

```
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32asound2 lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
```

After that I tried to install all the above mentioned pkg one by one and after installing "lib32z1" my problem was solved :)

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1

sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5

sudo apt-get install lib32bz2-1.0
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are having this problem, it's most likely you are on Precise 64-bit with Amazon EC2. They have fixed this for Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Same happens with Azure Ubuntu 13 VMs